# Not Loading Firebird Extension

Tags: php, apache, firebird

I'm trying to use the Firebird extension in PHP. I've got the extension files (`php_pdo_firebird.dll, php_interbase.dll`) in my `ext` folder. I'm adding them in my `php.ini` file like so

```
...
[PHP_PDO_FIREBIRD]
extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
[PHP_INTERBASE]
extension=php_interbase.dll
...
```

No errors are being thrown saying the extensions could not be loaded and yet whenever I print my `phpinfo` I don't see either of them listed. What am I missing here?

For what it's worth, I'm running PHP version 5.3.14 TS using Apache 2.2 on Windows 7.

**Edit:** It seems some errors are being logged, it's just that my `error_log` setting was being overwritten (for those seeing this, double check C:\Windows\Temp\php-errors.log). Now it's telling me the specified modules could not be found whenever the file clearly exists.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
    'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_pdo_firebird.dll' - 
    The specified module could not be found.
    in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
    'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_interbase.dll' - 
    The specified module could not be found.
    in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured it out! Okay, first to get the basics out of the way:

- Make sure the version of the DLLs matches your PHP version.
- For those who use the Windows installer, for some reason it doesn't provide an option to include the Interbase and Firebird modules so you'll have to download the matching .zip file and copy them from the `ext` folder in there.
- Double check for any typos, such as unescaped backslashes, in your `extension_dir` setting. This only applies if the value isn't "wrapped in quotation marks."

Now for the coup de grace. That error message is extremely misleading. At this point it should be finding your DLLs but it's missing one integral piece: `fbclient.dll` which can be found in the `bin` folder of your Firebird installation. Everywhere I read before said to place `fbclient.dll` in the `ext` folder but it *only* works if you put it in the root of your `PHP` folder.

Hope this helps future wayward souls :)

Comment: Thanks Mike I stuck in same situation today . Your answer helped me :)

Comment: If you are using XAMPP and you end up here like me, I found my answer here: http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/07/php-windows-install-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php_mssql-dll-php_pspell-dll-etc/

Copy FbClient.dll it in the %apache_home%\bin

Comment: @gigasean Though I tried putting the the fbclient.dll in the root of the PHP folder like Mike C said, it only worked when I copied it to the %apache_home%/bin as you said, so thank you verymuch. I still wonder why this works. My firebird/bin folder is in the PATH and so is the PHP folder. I was using WAMP and not XAMPP, but I guess that is irrelevant

Comment: if you put it in your windows/system(32) folder it should work also

Comment: for me copying fbclient.dll to apache/bin folder worked