# IIS+PHP 7 +Firebird

Tags: php, iis, firebird

I am trying to configure IIS+PHP 7 + firebird.
IIS and PHP are working fine but when I try to connect to a firebird db it shows this message:

"Could not connect to localhost: We were unable to use the Firebird database because the ibase extension for PHP is not installed. Check your PHP.ini to see how you can enable it. Check out the documentation to see how to install the extension."

I  have removed the semicolon of: "extension=php_interbase.dll"
I have added the php dir to the "Windows PATH" but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not Loading Firebird Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709380/not-loading-firebird-extension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check with phpinfo() frunction if ibase extenstion is installed or not.

If it is not listed, make sure extension=php_interbase.dll from your php.ini file is uncommented and if php_interbase.dll is present in extensions dirrectory.

Next make sure fbclient.dll is available in %PATH% because it is required by PHP ibase extension.